# How do you become a "Trusted Community Member"?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

When I submit a suggested edit, a notice would say that my edit "Won't be viewable to other people until it is approved by trusted community members" (sorry if I did a quotation mistake), but it doesn't specify how much reputation is required to become a "trusted community member."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although not stated explicitly, I think this is referenced at the [access review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) privilege page.  I believe you need 2,000 reputation points on this site (Meta Stack Exchange) to become a trusted community member (for approving suggested edits purposes), because it says:

> [Suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/review-suggested-edits) - 2,000 reputation

That number may be different on other sites so check their access review queues privilege pages to see what applies to your site.

This is different to the [trusted user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) privilege (20,000 on this site) so I can understand your difficulty finding it.

Comment: Some detailed information is on the FAQ page *[What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/what-are-the-reputation-requirements-for-privileges-on-sites-and-how-do-they-di/160292#160292)*, in particular in the many footnotes.

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q That's where I found the trusted user link.